# Get the element+1 and element-1 of a dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am using this code to put data of a specific list a new dataframe! This code works fine but I need to add data of index-1 and index+1 of every elemet I add to this dataframe.
For example I add data which have the index "70" I want also to add data of index "71".

NB: **Filtered_Data** is the whole dataframe , **df** is the new data frame which contains data of a specific condition

Here is my code, what should I add to get the data of indexes+1 and indexes-1 to this dataframe!
Thanks you in advance!!

```
hra_cc = HRA['COUNTRYCODE'].values.tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame()
for dest in Filtered_Data['COUNTRYCODE']:
    if dest in hra_cc:
        df=df.append(Filtered_Data.loc[Filtered_Data['COUNTRYCODE']==dest])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a for loop, it would be better to build up a mask of the original dataframe that matches your condition.  There's probably a better way to do this but here's one.

You didn't give any sample data, but I'm assuming your data looks something like this:

```
>>> hra_cc = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
>>> filtered_data = pd.DataFrame({'COUNTRYCODE': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'aa', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'bb', 'xx']})
```

You can get a mask of `filtered_data['COUNTRYCODE']` matching the given codes like:

```
>>> mask = filtered_data['COUNTRYCODE'].isin(hra_cc)
>>> mask
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
Name: COUNTRYCODE, dtype: bool
```

Now you just want the positions in the mask above and below each `True` to be set to `True` as well.  There are several ways to do this.  One way could be to use the shift method on the mask by 1 and then by -1 to shift the mask up and down and then OR it with the original mask:

```
>>> mask2 = mask | mask.shift(1)
>>> mask2 |= mask.shift(-1)
```

Now:

```
>>> df = filtered_data.loc[mask2]
>>> df
   COUNTRYCODE
0           aa
1           bb
2           cc
3           dd
5           ff
6           aa
7           cc
8           dd
9           ee
10          bb
11          xx
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your answer!